# "включение" и "выключение" эффекта

Tags: c#, unity3d

При нажатии на объект - объект должен "исчезать", а на его месте должен появляться эффект.

```
public class Disappearance : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject eff;
    public GameObject objectX;

    void Start()
    {
        eff.SetActive(false);
    }

    void Update()
    {
        if(Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
        {
            eff.SetActive(true);
            Destroy(GetComponent<MeshRenderer>());
        }
    }
}
```

Эффект (particle system) является ребенком объекта, и эффект сразу же проигрывается, как только запускается игра, что не так?((

Answer (score 0):

Нужно было использовать Instantiate() с массивом объектов ;)